# update textview from couchdb using changelistener android

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I am trying to get real time changes on a document using the changelistener, however i have to refresh tha mobile app to see the change. Here is my gist https://gist.github.com/mikekaraa/89416ea8b074c71d7153

Please help me out if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Would you tie your ChangeListener() event to a time interval such that e.g after every 3 or 5 seconds it is fired and triggers the next sequence of events if at all the document changed within that time span.
I hope that helps.